# Postgres replication + incremental backup

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Is it possible to have replication and incremental backup on the same setup

I would like to have high availability setup.  On the main site I will have two servers with replication between them and pgpool will handle the failover in case the primary server goes down.

I would also like to have another remote site for geographical redundancy.  This site will be active only if the main site is no longer functioning.   The remote site does not need to be updated in real-time.  Therefore, if it saves resources I thought about having incremental backup and restore from the main site to the remote site.  In other words the main site primary server will replicate its data to the main site secondary server.  In addition it will also generate incremental backup and that backup will be restored on the remote site.

From your answer I understood that it is possible to have both replication and incremental backup.  However, will this solution be better (resource consumption, reliability etc.) than just have replication to both the main secondary server and the remote site server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have PITR and streaming replication in use at the same time. Streaming replication can fall back to restoring from the WAL archive if it loses direct connectivity to the master too.

Lots more detail in the manual. It's hard to be more specific with a rather open and vague question - what, exactly, do you mean by "incremental backup"? etc.